# How to add item from select dropdown - keen-ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vue.js

I am making a Dynamic Form that will let users generate an image with their game stat automatically with vue.js and it utilises Keen-ui. I am new to vue.js and started learning it for the past 2 weeks.

Now, I am having an issue with the select dropdown with keen-ui. What I am trying to achieve is to have a functional dropdown that will let the user select a gamemode and when selected, it will add the query string.

For example:
`https://example.com/hive/stats/bedrock/dr?bg=dark&player=ntmnathan`

- The "dr" is a select option
- The "bg" is a select option
- The "player" is a text box input.

Unfortunately, the select dropdown isn't working for me, I've used text box inputs in all of them and they seemed to work perfect and add to the link.

Demo: https://codepen.io/Nathantominecraft/pen/RwWRVPZ

**index.html**

```html
      <div class="card-body" id="bedrockstatscard">

    <ui-select has-search label="Hive Gamemode" placeholder="Select a HiveMC Gamemode" v-model="game" :options="ga" @query-change="checkEvent"></ui-select>

      <ui-textbox label="Background" name="bg" validation-rules="required" :value.sync="bg" placeholder="dark, light, gamecode"></ui-textbox>

      <ui-textbox label="Player Username (Xbox Gamertag)" name="player" validation-rules="required" :value.sync="player" placeholder="NTMNathan"></ui-textbox>

    <div class="preview">
      <ul>
        <li>Image URL: <a :href="url"><span v-text="url"></span></a></li>
      </ul>

        <div class="preview-image">
          <img class="img-fluid" alt="Image will preview here." :src="url" onerror="this.src='https://i.imgur.com/5IC3llP.png';"/>
        </div>
    </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**custom.js**

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#bedrockstatscard',

    data() {
        return {
            baseUrl: 'https://example.com/hive/stats/bedrock',
            game: '',
            game: ['dr', 'wars', 'hide', 'murder', 'sg'],
            bg: '',
            player: ''
        }
    },
    methods: {
        checkEvent (val) {
            this.baseUrl += '/' + val
            this.game = val
        }
    },
    computed: {
        url() {
            var url = this.baseUrl;

            if (this.bg.length) {
                url += '?bg=' + this.bg;
            }

             if (this.player.length) {
                url += '&player=' + this.player;
            }

            return url;

      }
    }

});
```

What could I be doing wrong here? Again. Sorry I am new to using vue.js and I tried my best to provide as much. It would be great if there is anyone who is experienced at keen-ui as well to give me a hand here.

Comment: you can use https://codesandbox.io/ to provide a working snippet so that it will be easy for others to help you

Comment: Heres the working snippet. https://codepen.io/Nathantominecraft/pen/RwWRVPZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are not using the `ga` variable in `data()`. Just correct it and options will be shown in the dropdown.

```
data() {
        return {
            baseUrl: 'https://example.com/hive/stats/bedrock',
            game: '',
            ga: ['dr', 'wars', 'hide', 'murder', 'sg'],
            bg: '',
            player: ''
        }
    }
```

EDIT: In your computed method `url` you can add this:

```
if (this.game) {
  url += this.baseUrl + `/${this.game}`
}
```

and for ui-select directive use `:value.sync` instead of 'v-model`. Also if you need to listen to any changes then use`@input` method.

```
:value.sync="game"
```

Updated codepen link with working code:
https://codepen.io/sudheer-ranga/pen/vYNKmLZ

Comment: Yes, the Dropdown works but it is not querying the Image link. When its selected, it should be like:
The "dr" query comes from the Dropdown and that isn't working
https://example.com/hive/stats/bedrock/dr?player=test&bg=dark

Comment: Hmm, the whole links seems to be duplicating. Again thanks!
EDIT: not anymore.

Comment: Great, 1 more thing. Seems to be an undefined in the second dropdown for bg (Background). I just made a 2nd codepen so you can see: https://codepen.io/Nathantominecraft/pen/pojbPQv

Comment: I am not able to see any second dropdown for bg or any undefined value. Can you explain a bit?

Comment: Reload the page to see again, apologies for that. The undefined should be the "ga" that was selected from the first dropdown

Comment: updated here. https://codepen.io/sudheer-ranga/pen/NWGrgyx but you need to remove the added `game` to the `bgs` array when changing the `games`

Comment: When I do the form first time, it works fine but doing it 2nd time. the game that was selected from the first time will still be in the bgs array. It should be removed when changing games. I can't seem to figure this out and not sure what you meant in the last comment.